# Kill another process after the crash of the main app

Tags: c#

The main app starts another process, how can I end up this secondary process after the crash of the main app?

Answer (score 4):

Make the secondary process wait on the handle of its parent. If the parent exists for any reason, exit the child itself.

Comment: +1 But, you might want to expand that a bit. For example, how the child process (reliably) knows the handle of its parent (e.g. by passing the PID to the child as a command line argument and then get the handle from that).

Comment: Unfortunately i have no source codes for the second process. So I just can't wait for the parent.

Comment: Ok then you need to create a third process that acts as the watchdog. if(exited(pid1)) kill(pid2)

Comment: if I create the new third process and a user finishes it, then my logic will be lost. I need something that will be controlled by OS

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the user finishing it. Why would a user manually kill your watchdog process? What does "controlled by the OS" mean?

Answer (score 1):

you would need a watchdog process. but then... *quis custodiet custodes*?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your main process **does not crash!** - This is your first problem ..

If you can't ensure this, then you need a [Watchdog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start the new process in background thread. This way whenever your main app closed or crashed i.e. main thread terminates, the background thread will terminated automatically....